# Guardar promesa en una variable node js

Tags: nodejs

Como puedo guardar una promesa en una variable... tengo la siguiente llamada a la funcion que me retorna result:

```js
reverseGeocoding(lat, log)
.then(result => {
  console.log(result)
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Quiero almacenar en una variable origen.

Comment: dentro del then puedes agregar tus variables

Comment: Hola, ¿qué version de Node estás usando?

Answer (score 2):

Espero esto sea de ayuda

```
var nextAux;// si esta antes
reverseGeocoding(lat, log)
.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
  var aux= result; // si lo quieres hacer dentro
  nextAux= result
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Únicamente debes estar seguro que la variable de la promesa coincida con la variable donde la guardaras

Comment: No entiendo la utilidad del código. ¿Cuál es?

Comment: ejemplificar donde ubicar las variables que contendran la promesa

Comment: Me da la impresión que desea obtener `result` sin usar `then`. En ese caso, lo podría hacer con `await`.

Comment: tienes razon deberia usar await y async

Comment: @gugadev En si tengo que recibir 2 parametros "lat,long" mediante la funcion geocoding a la api de google maps que me genera coordenadas, luego tengo que retornar el JSON que me devuelve la funcion geocoding y almacenar en una variable origen o destino para despues interactuar con los valores que almaceno en las variables origen o destino, algo asi: let origen = geocoding(lat,long)
console.log(origen)

Comment: Echa un vistazo al siguiente enlace let origen= await geocoding(lat,long); https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/async-await-in-typescript-tutorial/

Comment: @Nik necesitas entender cómo funciona una promesa en JavaScript y qué significa que una rutina sea asíncrona. En en link que te puse describo qué es una promesa; puedes empezar por allí y averiguar más.