# Devolucion de valor return en node js, almacenar en una variable global y llamar a dicha variable desde cualquier lugar de la aplicacion

Tags: nodejs

Estoy haciendo una petición a la API de Google Maps, pero el detalle es que no me retorna el valor de result cuando ejecuto el programa

```
function reverseGeocoding(lat,long){
let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
latlng="+lat+","+long+"&key=AIzaSyBE-Ew1PqSOVZAD6ZlFe0u_XpVbfkajsd0"
return new Promise((ok, fail) => {
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  //console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
  if(error){ 
    fail(error); 
  }else { 
    ok(JSON.parse(body)); 
  }
});
})
};

let origen;
reverseGeocoding(-15.850519, -70.026469)
        .then(result => {
          origen = result
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
let direccion = `la direccion es: ${origen}`;
console.log(direccion);

let string = `el string es: ${origen}`;
console.log(string);

console.log(origen);
```

necesito mostrar la direccion desde cualquier lugar de la aplicacion...

Comment: Hola, ¿qué versión de Node estás usando?

Comment: Te he proporcionado links anteriormente, pero parece que no lo has leído. Tienes que investigar sobre: Promesas, callbacks y funciones asíncronas. Una vez entendido eso, podrás dar con la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

En tu pregunta (y también en [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/263977/guardar-promesa-en-una-variable-node-js)) no dices la versión de Node que estás usando, por lo tanto en mi respuesta voy a asumir que usas Node v7.10.1 o superior, dado que usaré las características de funciones asíncronas con `async/await`. Puedes consultar las características soportadas por cada versión de NodeJS en [Node Green](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions).

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea establecer el valor de una variable global en NodeJS usando como datos el resultado de una Promesa devuelta por una función que realiza una petición a  la API de Google Maps. Lo que se requiere es poder usar dicha variable global en cualquier parte del programa.

**SOLUCIÓN**

NodeJS v7.10.1 o superior incorpora la posibilidad de usar las características de ES2017: `async/await`.

Sin embargo, el ámbito global de NodeJS no es asíncrono, es decir, no podemos usar directamente la siguiente sentencia:

```
let origen = await reverseGeocoding(lat,long);
```

sin que dicha sentencia se encuentre dentro de una función asíncrona.

En Google Chrome y en Mozilla Firefox se puede usar en el ámbito global la sentencia `await` directamente. (Ojo sólo en el ámbito global). Tengo entendido que actualmente esta característica ha sido propuesta en NodeJS, puedes consultar el estado de dicha propuesta [aquí](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await).

Para resolver el problema, vamos a usar un pequeño truco, y no me refiero a magia.

Si el problema es usar `await` en el ámbito global, pues haremos que nuestra aplicación se encuentre dentro de una función asíncrona y listo.

Para eso simplemente creamos una función que servirá de envoltorio a toda nuestra aplicación, de tal manera, podremos hacer uso de la sentencia `await` para cualquier llamada a una función asíncrona dentro de nuestro programa.

Digo truco, porque las variables de nuestra aplicación realmente no estarán en el ámbito global, sino que pertenecerán al ámbito de nuestra función envoltorio. Si esto no es un problema, la solución es inmediata.

Supongamos que tu aplicación se inicia llamando a un archivo `index.js`.

Si envolvemos el código actual de tu archivo `index.js` dentro de una función asíncrona, podríamos tener lo siguiente:

**index.js**

```
(async () => {/* aqui va el contenido de tu programa */ })();
```

Como puedes apreciar, es algo bastante simple. Además, estamos realizando el llamando a la función envoltorio al momento de ejecutar nuestra aplicación. Esto es muy importante, porque si no hacemos el llamado, simplemente nuestra aplicación no se ejecutará.

Suponiendo que el código de tu aplicación es exactamente lo que has posteado, una forma de tener esto en funcionamiento sería:

```
//Empieza función envoltorio
(async () => {
  //...
  //Aquí también puedes hacer require
  //...

  function reverseGeocoding(lat,long){
    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+long+"&key=AIzaSyBE-Ew1PqSOVZAD6ZlFe0u_XpVbfkajsd0"
    return new Promise((ok, fail) => {
      request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        //console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
        if(error){ 
          fail(error); 
        } else { 
          ok(JSON.parse(body)); 
        }
      });
    });
  };

  // hacemos uso de await
  let origen = await reverseGeocoding(-15.850519, -70.026469);

  // ya puedes usar origen como gustes
  let direccion = `la direccion es: ${origen}`;
  console.log(direccion);

  let string = `el string es: ${origen}`;
  console.log(string);

  console.log(origen);

})();
//Fin de función envoltorio
```

De esta forma puedes realizar la tarea que estás intentando.

**CONCLUSIÓN**

Como conclusión tenemos que NodeJS no permite (aún) el uso de la sentencia `await` en el ámbito Global, por lo tanto toda vez que queramos usar la sentencia `await` en NodeJS, la misma debe estar dentro de una función asíncrona declarada con `async`.

Las variables que se declaran (usando `let` o `const`) dentro de nuestra función envoltorio no serán variables globales sino que pertenecerán al ámbito de nuestra función.

Si vamos a usar una función envoltorio para nuestra aplicación, debemos asegurarnos de realizar la llamada de la misma.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.