# Poner resultado de una consulta MySQL en otro fragemento de codigo en Node.JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

tengo el siguiente codigo en Node.JS, es una consulta al query:

```
    var result; <-- Variable global
    function main() {

    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "xxx",
      user: "admin",
      password: "xxxx",
      database: "mysql",
      port:23723
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query("SELECT * FROM db", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //Aqui debería ir el resultado original de la funcion
      });
    });
    }

function resultado(){
    console.log(result)
}


resultado()
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que el resultado del query que es la variable `result` lo ocupe en otra función. Y aunque ya hice la variable `result` global no me permite usar el resultado de `result` en otra función. ¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto?

Comment: y por qué no sólo le pasas el result como un parámetro a tu función? **funcionDos(result)**

Comment: @PakLeiChong me marca "undefined"

Comment: Como dice @PakLeiChong deberías pasar como parámetro tu result a la función en la que lo deseas utilizar; ahora bien, si te marca undefined significa que tu consulta no trae nada o en algún momento falla la ejecución. Debugueaste?

Comment: para que declarar una variable global?, para poderla usar en una funcion, algo no te dice que el valor que devuelva probablemente sea equivocado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Tienes varios detalles que mejorar en la forma en la que tienes escrita tu implementación.

En primer lugar, evita usar la sentencia `var` para la declaración de tus variables. Ya hace bastante tiempo se usa `let` y `const` para realizar la declaración de variables. A partir de la versión 6.4 de NodeJS, ambas sentencias están totalmente [soportadas](https://node.green/#ES2015-bindings).

En segundo lugar, el módulo [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) para NodeJS, usa el antiguo sistema de [funciones callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), las cuales normalmente:

> ...  se utilizan para continuar con la ejecución del código después de que se haya completado una operación a sincrónica  — estas se denominan devoluciones de llamada asincrónicas.

Con esto quiero decir que los métodos que implementa el módulo `mysql` son métodos a sincrónicos, por lo tanto las asignaciones de los resultados de dichos métodos no estarán disponibles inmediatamente luego de realizar la llamada al método.
Además, veo que intentas hacer lo siguiente:

```
var result; //<-- Variable global
...
con.query("SELECT * FROM db", function (err, result, fields) {
// la variable 'result' que se utiliza  aquí: ^^^ , no es la misma que has declarado anteriormente.
```

Como indico en el comentario del código anterior, la variable `result` pasada a la función callback, no es ni de casualidad la misma que has declarado globalmente. Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
// aqui utilizo 'var' para que no pienses que al declarar 
// la variable con 'let' estoy cambiando el alcance (scope) de la misma
var result = 'Variable result externa';

function asyncStuff(callback) {
  var doStuff = 'Variable interna';
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(null, doStuff);
  }, 2000);
}

// llamada a una función 'asíncrona' usando una función anónima como callback
// notemos que el valor que recibe como argumento es 'result'
asyncStuff((err, result) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(result);
});

// vvv Si le das al botón Ejecutar y esperas 2 segundos verás el resultado
```

Es claro que ambas variables pueden llamarse igual, pero dado que la segunda ha sido introducida como nombre del argumento de una función, la misma tendrá el alcance dentro de dicha función, por lo tanto es una dirección de memoria distinta de la que fue declarada globalmente.

Con esto ya vamos desenrollando la madeja y aclarando las cosas.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una solución para el problema que presentas con los métodos a sincrónicos de `mysql`, es envolver los mismos en una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas#Crear_una_promesa_alrededor_de_una_vieja_API_de_callbacks).

Una Promesa expone dos métodos llamados [`Resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/resolve) y [`Reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/reject), los cuales son llamados en caso de que la operación sea satisfactoria (se *resuelve* la promesa) o si ocurre un error (se rechaza la promesa).

Al envolver el método a sincrónico en una Promesa, podremos usar una función [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) para llamar a nuestra Promesa usando [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await).

Ahora bien, en tu caso, deseas realizar la consulta y usar el resultado en cualquier otra función o método. Al menos es lo que planteas en tu pregunta.

Para esto debes especificar el alcance que deseas darle al resultado. Por experiencia, es poco frecuente que el alcance sea global. Así que discutiré ese punto al final.

Una forma de envolver la API de `mysql` en una Promesa sería la siguiente:

```
const doQuery = (query) => {
  // Esta función devuelve una promesa, la cual será resuelta si la consulta es exitosa
  // y será rechazada en caso contrario.
  // Parámetros de entrada: query, el string que corresponde a la consulta a realizar
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
      if(error) return reject(error); // <- se rechaza la promesa y se pasa el motivo
      console.log('Query correcto.'); // mensaje de control
      return resolve(results); // <- se resuelve la Promesa y se pasa el resultado
    });
  });
}
```

Esta función sencilla crea un envoltorio para el método [`query`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries) de `mysql`. Se aprecia que si la consulta devuelve un error la Promesa es rechazada, y si la consulta es exitosa la Promesa es resuelta.

Adaptando esto al código de tu pregunta podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
function main() {
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "xxx",
      user: "admin",
      password: "xxxx",
      database: "mysql",
      port:23723
    });

    const doQuery = (query) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            con.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
                if(error) return reject(error);
                console.log('Consulta correcta');
                return resolve(results);
            });
        });
    }

    // si deseo utilizar el resultado de la consulta,
    // debo crear una función asíncrona y llamar a doQuery() usando await.
    const doStuffWithResults = async () => {
        const selectAllQuery = 'SELECT * FROM TableName';
        const results = await doQuery(selectAllQuery);
        console.log(results);
        // Aquí puedes usar el resultado de tu consulta
    }

    // llamamos a nuestro método
    doStuffWithResults();
}
```

Todo lo relacionado con el resultado de tu consulta, lo harías dentro del método `doStuffWithResults`. En este caso, la variable `results` sólo tiene alcance dentro del método `doStuffWithResults`.

Como mencioné anteriormente, tu planteamiento es usar el resultado de la consulta en otras funciones. Si lo anterior no es lo que deseas, puedes hacer que la variable `results` tenga un ámbito superior. En este caso el ámbito sería el de tu función `main()`. Para esto tu función `main()` la debes declarar como `async`.

El código podría quedar así:

```
async function main() {
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "xxx",
      user: "admin",
      password: "xxxx",
      database: "mysql",
      port:23723
    });

    const doQuery = (query) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            con.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
                if(error) return reject(error);
                console.log('Consulta correcta');
                return resolve(results);
            });
        });
    }

    const doStuffWithResults = (resultados) => {
        console.log(resultados);
        // Aquí haces cosas con los resultados
    }

    const doMoreStuffWithResults = (resultados) => {
        console.log(resultados);
        // Aquí haces más cosas con los resultados
    }

    // declaro mi consulta aquí
    const selectAllQuery = 'SELECT * FROM TableName';

    // realizo mi consulta aquí y el resultado lo almaceno en una variable
    const results = await doQuery(selectAllQuery);

    // llamamos a nuestros métodos y le pasamos el resultado para realizar tareas
    doStuffWithResults(results);
    doMoreStuffWithResults(results);
}
```

Por último, si lo que deseas es tener los resultados de tu consulta de forma global en toda tu aplicación, debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente: *el ámbito global de NodeJS no se ejecuta en una función asíncrona, es decir, no puedes usar directamente la sentencia `await` en el ámbito global de una aplicación Node*.

La solución a esto es un simple truco. Puedes leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264019/devolucion-de-valor-return-en-node-js-almacenar-en-una-variable-global-y-llamar/264126#264126) donde explico con detalle este truco. Pero en resumen lo que se hace es crear una función `async` que sea un envoltorio para toda tu aplicación, de esta forma podrías implementar `await` dentro de esta función envoltorio.

Espero que esto responda tus dudas.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes algunos problemas de asincronia.

La funcion resultado se esta ejecutando primero que la consulta.

Deberias hacer algo mas o menos asi

```js
  var resultaGlobal; <-- Variable global
    function main() {

    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "xxx",
      user: "admin",
      password: "xxxx",
      database: "mysql",
      port:23723
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query("SELECT * FROM db", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        resultaGlobal = result;
        resultado()
      });
    });
    }

function resultado(){
    console.log(resultaGlobal)
}
```