# Convertir callback a promises en NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas, callback

Para la realización de este ejercicio debo pasar los `callbacks` a `promises`.

Ya he mirado varios ejemplos pero no llego al objetivo, debido a que no hay un ejercicio tan parecido y apenas estoy conociendo y aprendiendo acerca de NODE.

Tengo la composición general de las `promises`, pero lo tengo haciendo uso de un archivo `.txt`, creando una copia del archivo con `promises`, pero acá no hay archivos.

Espero alguien por favor me pueda colaborar con el tema

1. Convertir las siguientes callback en promesas:

Callback #1

```
function multiplicaPorSiMismo(valor, ejecuta) { 

   console.log(`Inicia ejecución: el Valor es = 
   ${valor}`) 

   setTimeout(function() { 

   ejecuta(valor, valor * valor); 
   //ejecuta(2,2*2) 

   }, 1000) 
} 


multiplicaPorSiMismo(2, function(valor, resultado) { 
   console.log(`Finaliza con el valor = ${valor} y el 
   resultado = ${resultado}`) 
}) 
   console.log('Procesando')
```

Callback #2

```
function asincrono(valor, ejecucion) { 

    console.log(`Inicia ejecución: el Valor es = 
    ${valor}`) 
             setTimeout(function() { 
   ejecucion(valor, valor * valor) }, 0 | Math.random() 
   * 100) 
}  
   var max = 10; 
   var cnt = 0; 
   for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) { 
             asincrono(i, function(valor, resultado) { 
                     console.log(`Finaliza con el valor 
                      = ${valor} y el resultado = 
                      ${resultado}`) 

             if (++cnt === max) { 
                             console.log('Éxito') 
             } 
       }); 
}
```

EJEMPLO REALIZADO CON ARCHIVOS

```
const fs = require('fs'),
    file = './juegos.txt',
    newFile = './juegos_CALLBACK.txt' 
fs.access(file, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Archivo inexistente')
    } else {
        console.log('El archivo existe')
        fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('NO SE PUDO LEER EL ARCHIVO')
            } else {
                console.log('Se ha leido exitosamente el archivo')
                fs.writeFile(newFile, data, (err) => {
                    //return if(err){console.log('nosepudocop')}else{console.log('se ha copiado)}
                    return (err) ? console.log('NO SE PUDO COPIAR EL ARCHIVO') : console.log('El ARCHIVO SE COPIO CON EXITO')
                    //Operador ternario: Simplificacion de una sentencia if - else
                    /*
                    if(err){
                        console.log('tal cosa')
                    }else{
                        console.log('otra cosa')
                    }
                    */
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

PROMISE

```
const fs = require('fs')
file = './juegos.txt',
newFile = './juegos_PROMISES.txt',

promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    fs.access(file, fs.f_OK, (err)=>{
        return (err) ? reject(new Error('Archivo inexistente')):resolve(true)
    })
}).then((dataPromise)=>{
    console.log('el archivo existe')
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject)=>{
        fs.readFile(file,(err,data)=>{
            return(err)?reject(new Error('problemas del archivo')):resolve(data)
        })
    })
}).then((dataPromise)=>{
    console.log('Lectura exitosa del archivo')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        fs.writeFile(newFile, dataPromise, (err)=>{
            return (err)?reject(new Error('no fue posible copiar')):resolve('Se ha copiado el archivo exitosamente')
        })
    })
}).then((dataPromise)=>{
    console.log(dataPromise)
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err.message)
})
```

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta carece de un [mcve] de lo que hayas intentado. Por favor, si crees que puedes mejorar tu pregunta agregando el código de lo que lleves avanzado, has clic en [edit]. De lo contrario va a ser difícil ayudarte con tu ejercicio y sacarás mala nota. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya agregue el ejemplo pero por ser con archivos no se como iria la estructura ahora.

Comment: Disculpa por ser tan insistente en este tema del código, pero es que lo que dices tener (que funciona con operaciones sobre archivos) no tiene nada que ver con lo que te piden en el ejercicio. Si bien se usan [*Promises*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise), lo ideal es que intentaras por ti mismo realizar el ejercicio. Podrías leer [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273216/poner-resultado-de-una-consulta-mysql-en-otro-fragemento-de-codigo-en-node-js/274929#274929) respuesta donde doy una explicación para lo que buscas. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

La manera de hacerlo es haciendo un wrapper de una promesa. Ejemplo:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function renameFile (oldName, newName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.rename(oldName, newName, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }

      resolve(true)
    });    
  })
}

renameFile('path/to/my/file', 'path/to/my/fileNewName')
  .then(() => console.log('done'))
  .catch((e) => console.error(e.message))
```

Comment: la linea `return reject(err)` no va el return